# How to upload and download Video using QuickBlox in Swift

Tags: quickblox

I am uploading image and video to QuickBlox. My upload is successful but when i download the following scenarios occour:
1) In case of image i am able to download image and show (No issues in this)
2) My question is about video with below points
a) I am able upload video successfully
b) How would i be able to recognize the extension of video from server? I need sample code for uploading and downloading video from the QuickBlox. As if i upload .mov file then what should be the filetype and what should be in case of .mp4 and so on. And when i download the file how would i know the correct extension for the file and then how to get the correct file from the server and save it.

Answer (score 1):

When uploading a video, set the type to "video" in the attachment and the corresponding content type, for example "video/mp4":

```
QBRequest.uploadFile(with: localVideoUrl, fileName: nameVideo, contentType: "video/mp4", isPublic: true,

successBlock: { (response: QBResponse, uploadedBlob: QBCBlob) -> Void in

let attachment = QBChatAttachment()

attachment.id = uploadedBlob.uid

attachment.name = uploadedBlob.name

attachment.type = "video"

attachment["size"] = "\(uploadedBlob.size)"

// send message with attachment

}, statusBlock: { (request : QBRequest?, status : QBRequestStatus?) -> Void in

let progress = CGFloat(Float(status.percentOfCompletion))

// show progress

}

}) { (response : QBResponse) -> Void in

//error handler

}
```

When you receive a message with attachment and attachment type is "video”, refer to this example:

```
let attachment = message.attachments?.first

if attachment.type == "video" {

QBRequest.downloadFile(withUID: attachment.id, successBlock: { (response: QBResponse, fileData: Data) in

let fileData = fileData as NSData

let fileName = ID + "_" + attachment.name

let filePath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + fileName

let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

if fileData.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true) == true {

//do what you need with the video - cache, save, play, etc.

} else {

print("failure write")

}

}, statusBlock: { (request: QBRequest, status: QBRequestStatus?) in

let progress = CGFloat(status.percentOfCompletion)

//show progress

}, errorBlock: { (response: QBResponse) in

//error handler

})

}
```

Comment: team thanks...but what about ".mov" or other type of video files ?

Comment: @AshishGupta Quickblox supports all video types supported by iOS platform. In case of a '.mov' file, you need to use _contentType: "video/quicktime"_ as per example above. You can check the full list of correct MIME types [here](https://help.encoding.com/knowledge-base/article/correct-mime-types-for-serving-video-files/)

Comment: Thanks...But how would i get the mime type in response from the server as i get data obj from there

Comment: usually you would set a name along with mime_type, for example:
let attachment = QBChatAttachment()
                        attachment.id = uploadedBlob.uid
                        attachment.name = uploadedBlob.name
                        attachment.type = "video"
                        attachment["size"] = "\(uploadedBlob.size)"
After successful download you receive `uploadedBlob: QBCBlob` and its name is set here: `attachment.name = uploadedBlob.name`
In this way, you can check `pathExtension` from the name.

Comment: That means i just have to use some trick to do that.No other means ?